# Trouble splitting an array in @PostConstruct Method of my Kafka SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm creating a Kafka Springboot listener that tracks the state of an object.  I have the kafka portion working and am able to listen to the topics.  I am using a Tree map to map a string key that is the topic to an object.  The topic name actually contains some information that I want to use to initialize the object.   My question is this ( I apologize, I'm not very familiar with SpringBoot).

In my Post Construct method, I have a string array that is coming in called locoTopics.  I've verified that strings are coming in and they are of the form "ignore.ignore.mark.id".  The issue I'm running into is that when I try to split the string in the Post Construct method it appears to return null even though the string definitely contains the "." expression.  I say it appears, because the program appears to jump forward and skip several lines of code.   To be precise, when I debug.  It appears to go from the  "String [] locoArray = locoTopics[i].split("\.");" line to my Object constructor immediately and skip all the steps in between.   Then it appears to jump in and out of the loop.   I'm very confused why this is.  Is this something related to SpringBoot that is happening or am I missing something in my code?   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```java
public class InitTrackerReceiver {
    // instance variables
    Map mapr = new TreeMap<String, Locomotive>();
    String[] locoTopics;
    public List<String> m_failureCodes;

    // Moved Functionality to get loco ids into separate class, Locomotive IDs now
    // gets locoids
    @Autowired
    public LocomotiveIDs locomotiveIDs;

    //This is where loco objects will be instantiated
    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeLocomotives() {
        // grab loco topic strings and separate into a string array
        locoTopics = locomotiveIDs.getLocoString();

        // Go through the loco topics from application.properties and create a Loco
        // object with that string as identifier
        for (int i = 0; i < locoTopics.length; i++) {
           String [] locoArray = locoTopics[i].split("\\.");
           String markString = locoArray[2];
           String scacString = "name";
           String idString = locoArray[3];
           mapr.put(locoTopics[i], new Locomotive(locoTopics[i], markString, scacString, idString));
      }
    }

    @Value("#{'${failure.init.messagefields}'.split(',')}")
    List<String> typesToFail;
```

Comment: Did you check the return of `locomotiveIDs.getLocoString()`? Is it what you expected?

Comment: Yes, it is an array of strings of the form ["ignore1.ignore1.mark1.id1", "ignore2.ignore2.mark2.id2" .........]    All the way up to the locoTopics[i] everything works as expected.  and in fact when I remove the string splitting portion out and change my constructor on the loco to accept the whole string.  It works just fine.  It only has issues when the string split commands are put in there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd go ahead and follow up with the answer.   I have no clue how this happened, but the code that was in Eclipse that was in the debugger was not the same code that was running.  I don't know if this was a bug in EGIT or Eclipse.   It became apparent when I ran a Maven clean and my project would no longer launch.   Whenever I tried to debug, it would launch and say that it couldn't find the main class, which was my Spring application launch class.   I did a Maven Build and that seemed to get everything in sync.   Then the code started working as expected.